# azure identity java sdk throwing MutableCoercionConfig error

Tags: java, azure, scala, databricks, azure-identity

### I'm new to the java library, I learned that azure Java SDK can be used in the scala environment, So I have tried using the azure identity library in the data bricks environment

> DBR Version 7.3 LTS

> scala 2.12

> maven coordinate com.azure:azure-identity:1.3.5

pls help me resolve the error,

here is the code :

```
    import com.azure.identity._;
    import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder;
    
    
    val clientID = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="****",key="****");
    val ClientSecret = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="****",key="****");
    val tenantID = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="****",key="****");
    val endpoint = "****" ;
    
    val clientSecretCredential:ClientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder().tenantId(tenantID).clientId(clientID).clientSecret(ClientSecret).build();
```

here is the error i face
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.coercionConfigDefaults()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MutableCoercionConfig**

```
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:145)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:127)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.builder(XmlMapper.java:218)
    at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.<init>(JacksonAdapter.java:137)
    at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.createDefaultSerializerAdapter(JacksonAdapter.java:189)
    at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient.<clinit>(IdentityClient.java:96)
    at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClientBuilder.build(IdentityClientBuilder.java:113)
    at com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential.<init>(ClientSecretCredential.java:50)
    at com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder.build(ClientSecretCredentialBuilder.java:76)
    at linea34e0846b16045d09ff78af8b346393c25.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-626790621540495:18)
    at linea34e0846b16045d09ff78af8b346393c25.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-626790621540495:68)
    at linea34e0846b16045d09ff78af8b346393c25.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-626790621540495:70)
    at linea34e0846b16045d09ff78af8b346393c25.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-626790621540495:72)
    at linea34e0846b16045d09ff78af8b346393c25.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-626790621540495:74)
    at linea34e0846b16045d09ff78af8b346393c25.$read$$iw.<init>(command-626790621540495:76)
    at linea34e0846b16045d09ff78af8b346393c25.$read.<init>(command-626790621540495:78)
    at linea34e0846b16045d09ff78af8b346393c25.$read$.<init>(command-626790621540495:82)
    at linea34e0846b16045d09ff78af8b346393c25.$read$.<clinit>(command-626790621540495)
    at linea34e0846b16045d09ff78af8b346393c25.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at linea34e0846b16045d09ff78af8b346393c25.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at linea34e0846b16045d09ff78af8b346393c25.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:745)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1021)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:574)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:37)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:600)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:570)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:219)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.$anonfun$repl$1(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:204)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:789)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:742)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:204)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$10(DriverLocal.scala:431)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:239)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:234)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:231)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:48)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:276)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:269)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:48)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:408)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:653)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:645)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:486)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:598)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:391)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?